# id3 package returning null values - Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a music player in Flutter and it is using the [id3 package](https://pub.dev/packages/id3) to read metadata from the given media file. But for some reason it is only reading the first character or returning `null` for the fields.

This is the code

```
import 'package:id3/id3.dart';

Map<String, dynamic> meta = {'': ''};

void getMetadata(String path) {
  MP3Instance mp3instance = new MP3Instance(path);
  if (mp3instance.parseTagsSync()) {
    meta = mp3instance.getMetaTags();
    print(meta);
  }
}

String getTitle() {
  return meta["Title"];
}

String getArtist() {
  return meta["Artist"];
}

String getAlbum() {
  return meta["Album"];
}

String getAPIC() {
  String apic = meta["APIC"].toString();
  int index = apic.indexOf('base64:');
  int indexEnd = apic.indexOf('}');
  if (index != -1) {
    return apic.substring((index + 8), indexEnd);
  } else {
    return apic;
  }
}
```

and I am taking the values in an initState() to inflate the list view as follows

```
void initState() {
    _returnedSongs = returnMusicList();
    for (FileSystemEntity entity in _returnedSongs) {
      path.add(entity.path);
    }
    for (String str in path) {
      getMetadata(str);
      title = getTitle();
      artist = getTitle();
      album = getAlbum();
      apic = getAPIC();
      listMusic.add(Music(title, artist, album, apic));
    }
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

from this [issue](https://github.com/sanket143/id3/issues/2) seems like a bug within the plugin and one of the recommendations is to use [flutter_audio_query](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_audio_query)

> A Flutter plugin, Android only at this moment, that allows you query for audio metadata info about artists, albums, songs audio files and genres available on device storage. All work is made using Android native MediaStore API with ContentResolver API and query methods run in background thread. AndroidX support it's OK!